# ImageMagick using openJPEG 2.0 and CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6, centos6.5, imagemagick

I'm currently working on a CentOS 6.5 server. I'm trying to use **openjp2** as one of the delegates in ImageMagick.

Since openjpeg for CentOS is outdated (1.3), I've installed a new one using RPM package.

```
$ find /usr | grep openj
/usr/lib64/libopenjp2.so
/usr/lib64/libopenjp2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib64/openjpeg-2.0
/usr/lib64/openjpeg-2.0/OpenJPEGConfig.cmake
/usr/lib64/openjpeg-2.0/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake
/usr/lib64/openjpeg-2.0/OpenJPEGTargets-release.cmake
find: `/usr/lib64/audit': Permission denied
/usr/lib64/libopenjp2.so.6
/usr/share/doc/openjpeg2
/usr/share/doc/openjpeg2/CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/openjpeg2/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/openjpeg-2.0
/usr/share/doc/openjpeg-2.0/CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/openjpeg-2.0/LICENSE
/usr/share/man/man3/libopenjp2.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libopenjp2.3
/usr/lib/libopenjp2.so
/usr/lib/libopenjp2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/openjpeg-2.0
/usr/lib/openjpeg-2.0/OpenJPEGConfig.cmake
/usr/lib/openjpeg-2.0/OpenJPEGTargets-noconfig.cmake
/usr/lib/openjpeg-2.0/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake
/usr/lib/libopenjp2.so.6
/usr/include/openjpeg-2.0
/usr/include/openjpeg-2.0/openjpeg.h
/usr/include/openjpeg-2.0/opj_config.h
/usr/include/openjpeg-2.0/opj_stdint.h
```

Next, I'm trying to build IM version 6.8.8-2 using the following configure settings.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-modules --with-openjp2 --with-jpeg --with-png --with-tiff --enable-shared --disable-static
```

However, during the checking (logs), I found this.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
checking for LIBOPENJP2... no
```

And the result delegates are:

```
bzlib djvu mpeg fontconfig freetype gslib jng jpeg lcms openexr png ps rsvg tiff x xml zlib
```

Running `./configure --help`, I saw some flags you can pass.

```
LIBOPENJP2_CFLAGS
  C compiler flags for LIBOPENJP2, overriding pkg-config
LIBOPENJP2_LIBS
    linker flags for LIBOPENJP2, overriding pkg-config
```

Is there something that I need to specify during the `./configure`? It looks like IM cannot see the installed openjpeg.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention exactly what package you installed, but your error indicates that you didn't install its related `-devel` package, which is necessary to compile software against it.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue (on CentOS 7) and found that the problem was because I had not installed the `openjpeg-devel` package.

```
yum install openjpeg2-devel
```

While searching for solutions it also appears that ImageMagick currently only supports OpenJPEG 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling this was a bit painful, I should learn to read the logs :( ...
Indeed, you need to use the source for jp2 from [here](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/archive/v2.1.2.tar.gz)
Then compile as  required in INSTALL.md:

```
cmake .
make && make install
```

By default, installation is in /usr/local

Go to you ImageMagick source dir, then set:

```
export LIBOPENJP2_CFLAGS=/usr/local/include/openjpeg-2.1
export LIBOPENJP2_LIBS=/usr/local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Then you can compile ! (I've compile with perl, tiff, jpeg and jpeg2000).

```
./configure --enable-delegate-build --with-perl --enable-shared=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-tiff=yes --with-openjp2=yes && make && make install
```

Done !

```
$> convert -list
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-0 Q16 x86_64 2017-03-02 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg png tiff x zlib
Usage: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file
```